# Neural network doesn't classify sleep EEG recordings

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch

We have a problem with the code that I'm running in an academic course and I'd appreciate getting some help from someone on the forum.
We're trying to train a CNN model to classify EEG sleep recordings as male or female. It's something that was done in some papers but we use a different dataset in our course. The problem is that the network doesn't learn no matter what we do - we tried changing the number of the layers, the size of each layer, the learning rate, the number of epochs, the batch sizem the optimizer and also adding data.
We also tried using an RNN with a GRU (Gated Recurrent Unit) instead of a CNN but it didn't help.
Here are some examples of the network not learning:

[Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kr8yD.png)
[Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYUuG.png)

Note that the "test" dataset is actually validation.

We can't find any problem with the machine learning part of our code. We think that maybe the problem is with the data processing part but we're not sure so we wanted someone to check if he/she can find a problem with the machine learning part.
Before I should say that we have 200 8-hour recordings of sleep EEG obtained from 200 patients. These are 100 Hz recording. The shape of each sample is 4X2X1000 (4 batches X 2 EEG channels for each recording X 1000 voltage values representing 10 seconds of recording).

Here's the machine learning part (I post a lot of code in case someone says that more code is needed...):

```
import _pickle
import contextlib
import io
import torch
import os
import numpy as np
from aux_eegproj_funcs_simplified import *
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader, SubsetRandomSampler
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, f1_score, ConfusionMatrixDisplay
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tqdm import tqdm
import torchviz
import mne
```

```
# DATASET
table_name = 'sleep_1_10sec.csv' # name of the table from which we take the beginning and end time of each sample (subrecording)
eeg_ds = EEGDataset(EEGTransform, exp_table=build_experiment_tbl(table_name), filtered=0)  # EEGDataSet and EEGTransform are a class
batch_sz = 4 # batch size

# splitting the data to train, validation and test
dl_train, dl_val, dl_test = tt_split_by_pid_mf(dataset=eeg_ds, batch_size=batch_sz, train_rt=.8,  num_workers=0, verbose=1)
nF = sum(eeg_ds.table['sex (F=1)'][dl_train.sampler.indices] == 1)  # number of females
nM = sum(eeg_ds.table['sex (F=1)'][dl_train.sampler.indices] == 2)  # number of males
wF = nM / (nF + nM)  # females percentage
wM = nF / (nF + nM)  # males percentage
```

The model:

```
class eegSexNet(nn.Module):  # Define a network to classify Sex
    def __init__(self, input_shape):
        """
        :param input_shape: input tensor shape - every batch size will be ok as it is used to compute the FCs input size.
        """
        super().__init__()
        # Define the CNN layers in a nn.Sequential.
        # Remember to use the number of input channels as the first layer input shape.
        self.CNN = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv1d(in_channels=input_shape[1], out_channels=8, kernel_size=5, stride=1, padding=0, dilation=2),
            # TODO try changing the kernel sizes they were 3
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv1d(in_channels=8, out_channels=16, kernel_size=5, stride=1, padding=0, dilation=2),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv1d(in_channels=16, out_channels=32, kernel_size=5, stride=1, padding=0, dilation=2),
            nn.ReLU(),
            Residual(in_channels=32)
        )

        # Compute the CNN output size here to use as the input size for the fully-connected part.
        CNN_forward = self.CNN(torch.zeros(input_shape))

        self.FCs = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(CNN_forward.shape[1] * CNN_forward.shape[2], 10),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(10, 1),
            nn.Sigmoid()
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        # ------Your code------#
        # Forward through the CNN by passing x, flatten and then forward through the linears.
        features = self.CNN(x)
        features = features.view(features.size(0), -1)  # reshape/flatten
        scores = self.FCs(features)
        # ------^^^^^^^^^------#
        return torch.squeeze(scores)
```

Residual block used in the class of the model:

```
class Residual(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels):
        super().__init__()
        # Define self.direct_path by adding the layers into a nn.Sequential. Use nn.Conv1d and nn.Relu.
        # You can use padding to avoid reducing L size, to allow the skip-connection adding.
        self.direct_path = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv1d(in_channels=in_channels, out_channels=16, kernel_size=7, padding=3),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv1d(in_channels=16, out_channels=32, kernel_size=7, padding=3)
        )
        # You should use convolution layer with a kernel size of 1 to consider the case where the input and output shapes mismatch.
        skip_layers = []
        if in_channels != 32:  # HOW DOES THIS PART WORK? When are you adding the layers
            skip_layers.append(
                nn.Conv1d(in_channels=in_channels, out_channels=32, kernel_size=1, stride=1, padding=0, dilation=1,
                          bias=False)
            )
        else:
            self.skip_path = nn.Sequential(*skip_layers)

    def forward(self, x):
        # Compute the two paths and add the results to each other, then use ReLU (torch.relu) to activate the output.
        direct_output = self.direct_path(x)
        skip_output = self.skip_path(x)
        activated_output = torch.relu(direct_output + skip_output)
        return activated_output
```

Training loop:

```
def Train_Sex_Net(epochs=n_epochs, fn='None', optimizer=opt_sex, loss_function=bce):  # Training SEXNET
    global sex_net
    gpu_0 = torch.device(1)
    label = 0  # select the sex label
    train_loss_vec = []
    test_loss_vec = []
    train_acc_vec = []
    test_acc_vec = []
    for i_epoch in range(epochs):
        train_loss = 0
        test_loss = 0
        # Train set
        train_loss, y_true_train, y_pred_train = forward_epoch(sex_net, dl_train, loss_function, optimizer,
                                                                wM, train_loss,
                                                               to_train=True, desc='Train', device=gpu_0, label=label)
        # Test set
        test_loss, y_true_test, y_pred_test = forward_epoch(sex_net, dl_test, loss_function, optimizer, wM, test_loss,
                                                            to_train=False, desc='Test', device=gpu_0, label=label)

        # Metrics:
        train_loss = train_loss / len(dl_train)  # we want to get the mean over batches.
        test_loss = test_loss / len(dl_test)
        train_loss_vec.append(train_loss)
        test_loss_vec.append(test_loss)

        train_accuracy = accuracy_score(y_true_train.cpu(),
                                        (y_pred_train.cpu().detach() > 0.5) * 1)
        test_accuracy = accuracy_score(y_true_test.cpu(),
                                       (y_pred_test.cpu().detach() > 0.5) * 1)

        train_acc_vec.append(train_accuracy)
        test_acc_vec.append(test_accuracy)

        print('\n')
        print(f'train_loss={round(train_loss, 3)}; train_accuracy={round(train_accuracy, 3)} \
              test_loss={round(test_loss, 3)}; test_accuracy={round(test_accuracy, 3)}')

    return (train_loss_vec, train_acc_vec), (test_loss_vec, test_acc_vec) # (val_loss_vec, val_acc_vec)
```

Called by the training loop:

```
def forward_epoch(model, dl, loss_function, optimizer, weight, total_loss=0,
                  to_train=False, desc=None, device=torch.device('cpu'), label=0): # Training loop
    # label =0 is for sex
    # label = 1 is for Age
    # total loss is over the entire epoch
    # y_trues is by patient for the entire epoch; can get last batch with [-batch_size]
    # y_preds is by patient for the entire epoch
    #
    with tqdm(total=len(dl), desc=desc, ncols=100) as pbar:
        model = model.double().to(device)  # solving runtime memory issue

        y_trues = torch.empty(0).type(torch.int).to(device)
        y_preds = torch.empty(0).type(torch.int).to(device)
        for i_batch, (X, y) in enumerate(dl):
            X = X.to(device)
            X = X.type(torch.double)
            y = y[label].to(device)  # added index because of get label returning sex, age
            y_pred = model(X)  # Forward
            y_true = y.type(torch.double)  # Loss:
            y_true_copy = torch.clone(y_true)
            loss = loss_function(y_pred, y_true)  # loss of one batch
            total_loss += loss.item()

            y_trues = torch.cat((y_trues, y_true))
            y_preds = torch.cat((y_preds, y_pred))
            if to_train:
                optimizer.zero_grad()  #  Backward:zero the gradients to not accumulate their changes.
                loss.backward()  # get gradients
                optimizer.step()  # Optimization step: use gradients
            pbar.update(1)  # Progress bar

    return total_loss, y_trues, y_preds
```

Calling all the functions:

```
sex_net = eegSexNet(torch.Size([4, 2, 1000]))  # Instantiate the network

learning_rate = 0.0001
opt_sex = torch.optim.Adam(params=sex_net.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)  # Optimizer for eegnet
bce = nn.BCELoss()
n_epochs = 6
f0 = 'sex_k7'  # file format '.pickle' added automatically
train_res, test_res = Train_Sex_Net(epochs=n_epochs, fn=f0)
```

Does anyone see anything that might be wrong in the code? Or maybe the problem is in the data processing and choosing part that I didn't show?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The problem is that the network doesn't learn although there are no errors that I get. I want it to get a recording and say if the recording was obtained from a male or female. It can't do it. It says that almost all of the recordings were obtained from the same sex, although it's not true.

Comment: Please note that this does not have to be a programming problem, maybe there is just no relation between your input and the target.

Comment: Maybe, but as I said there are papers where they succeeded classifying with other EEG recordings.

Answer (score 0):

I went through the coding. In the class you've created as a model using CNN, adding a softmax layer MAY help you instead of the sigmoid function

```
tf.nn.softmax(
    logits, axis=None, name=None
)
```

The primary purpose of the softmax function is to transform the (unnormalized) output of K units (which is e.g. represented as a vector of K elements) of a fully-connected layer to a probability distribution (a normalized output).

Also, you have asked working of a part of the coding in the residual class:

```
if in_channels != 32:  # HOW DOES THIS PART WORK? When are you adding the layers
            skip_layers.append(
                nn.Conv1d(in_channels=in_channels, out_channels=32, kernel_size=1, stride=1, padding=0, dilation=1,
                          bias=False)
```

if the In_channel is not equal to 32, then the channel is said to be skipped and convoluted because, in the model you've created, you've tried to find the residual only for the in_channel of 32 size

```
nn.ReLU(),
            Residual(in_channels=32)
```

Comment: I think your EEG reading must be refined by setting thresholds like sleep time or using parameters related to your data. then apply the modified graph to the model. This would work. :)

Comment: Thanks. I actually had already set thresholds to define what's the sleep time.